how does the CombineHiveInputFormat split the files(ORC/TextFile)
set maxsize of splits:
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=209715200;   --200MB（256MB default）
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=0;

run the hive sql on a table STORED AS TEXTFILE, get 4 maps and their conters info as follow:
map_1
File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=440118
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=268452170
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=5
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=17895698
        Map output records=4
        Map output bytes=68
        Map output materialized bytes=100
        Input split bytes=353
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=4
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=660
        CPU time spent (ms)=29630
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=689143808
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2610499584
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=597688320
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=689225728
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2610499584

map_2
File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=440175
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=268434391
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=5
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=13043308
        Map output records=7
        Map output bytes=119
        Map output materialized bytes=157
        Input split bytes=339
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=7
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=677
        CPU time spent (ms)=25810
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=678891520
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2604634112
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=593494016
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=678891520
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2604634112

map_3:
File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=440175
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=218135763
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=5
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=12115805
        Map output records=7
        Map output bytes=119
        Map output materialized bytes=157
        Input split bytes=346
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=7
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=485
        CPU time spent (ms)=24320
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=685334528
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2606112768
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=609222656
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=685334528
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2606112768

map_4
File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=440175
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=92375013
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=4
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=4488345
        Map output records=7
        Map output bytes=119
        Map output materialized bytes=157
        Input split bytes=238
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=7
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=395
        CPU time spent (ms)=11290
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=684408832
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2605264896
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=567279616
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=684408832
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2605264896

and the files of talbe as follow:
[op-ma@Hadoop100 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/datasci.db/movies_score_class_raw
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 op-ma supergroup  268421787 2024-09-27 09:23 /user/hive/warehouse/datasci.db/movies_score_class_raw/000000_0
-rw-r--r--   3 op-ma supergroup  352340880 2024-10-04 12:55 /user/hive/warehouse/datasci.db/movies_score_class_raw/000000_0_copy_1
-rw-r--r--   3 op-ma supergroup  226584334 2024-09-27 09:23 /user/hive/warehouse/datasci.db/movies_score_class_raw/000001_0


my questing is how does the CombineHiveInputFormat splits the files, size of these splits produced so strange
I have trid read the source code to figure out how it's working but too many get_splits methods make me more confused and learned nothing, i also trid to change the maxsize of splits and found 2 splits alway have same size :218135763,92375013 and the size of first split always near 256MB, second one changed follow the maxsize configure
